# Tracking Bounced Emails Through ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, email, tracking, smtpclient, email-bounces

Is there any way I can track (through the code) the bounced emails.

Consider the email id like 'skdfisdcnsodioifs@gmail.com'. This is valid email id but does not exists so certainly it will be bounced backed.

I am using ASP.Net's SmtpClient with  "message.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure". However it still shows the message sent successfully and after ~20-25 minutes I get the fail delivery notification email.

Below is my code

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("xxxx.xxxxxx.xxx", 25);
        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("xxxxxx@xxxxxx.com", "xxxxxx");            
        MailAddress to = new MailAddress("abcdsfasdfasdfasdfasdf2342342defgh@gmail12333.com");
        MailAddress from = new MailAddress("xxxxxx@xxxxxx.com");            
        MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to);
        message.Headers.Add("Return-Path", "xxxxxx@gmail.com");
        message.ReplyToList.Add(new MailAddress("xxxxxx@gmail.com"));
        message.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure | DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnSuccess;
        message.Subject = "Test POC";
        message.Body = "This is a test e-mail message sent by an application. ";            
        client.SendCompleted += client_SendCompleted;            
        string UserState = "test"; 
        client.Timeout = 3;
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("start to send email ...");
            client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;                
            client.SendAsync(message,UserState);              
            Console.WriteLine("email was sent successfully!");
        }
        catch (SmtpFailedRecipientsException ep)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("failed to send email with the following error:");
            Console.WriteLine(ep.Message);
        } 
        catch (Exception ep)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("failed to send email with the following error:");
            Console.WriteLine(ep.Message);
        } 
        Console.WriteLine("test.");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static void client_SendCompleted(object sender, System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Get the unique identifier for this asynchronous operation.
        //String token = (string)e.UserState;
        if (e.Cancelled)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Send canceled.");
        }
        if (e.Error != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("[{0}] ", e.Error.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Message sent.");
        }        
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.
Abhishek

Comment: Not really, not using plain SMTP. It's just not designed to work that way. You could do a DNS lookup to check the domain is valid, but there's no way to check the whole email address is valid. If there was, we won't have SPAM.